# EF Code first and optional:optional relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

According to [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671314%28v=vs.113%29.aspx), the following should create an **optional:optional** relationship, but instead it creates **optional:many** relationship. Is the article wrong?

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Optional_1>()
            .HasKey(o1 => o1.id1);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Optional_2>()
            .HasKey(o2 => o2.id2);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Optional_1>()
            .HasOptional(o1 => o1.Dependent)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(o2 => o2.Principal);
    }

public class Optional_1
{
    public int id1 { get; set; }
    public Optional_2 Dependent { get; set; }
}

public class Optional_2
{
    public int id2 { get; set; }

    public Optional_1 Principal { get; set; }
}
```

thank you

Comment: Are you trying to create a one-to-one relationship? If so, then both ends must be required. Otherwise, what type of relationship are you trying to create?

Comment: @Brian Driscoll: I'm trying to create 0..1:0..1 relationship. According to the link I posted, this should be possible with Code first

Comment: 0..1:0..1 is not valid, in particular on the left side (principal side) of the relationship. Valid relationships are 1:0..1, 1:1, 1:many, or many:many. If you have two independent entities that don't necessarily have a direct principal:dependent relationship, then many:many is likely the best fit for your situation.

Comment: How do you think you would model a 0..1:0..1 relationship in your database? It would require nullable foreign keys w/ unique constraints on both sides of the relation, which would mean that you could only have a single null value on each side of the relation... thus making the vast majority of the relation tuples 1:1.

Comment: @Brian Driscoll: ups, I didn't notice your last comment. Any ideas whether article was talking about something else when referring to optional:optional relationship ( or perhaps article is simply wrong )?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll This is not correct. optional:optional is valid in EF. It might not be enforceable from a database perspective but it's enforceable from the framework side.

Comment: @Dismissile I didn't say optional:optional wasn't valid in EF, I just said that 0..1:0..1 is not a valid DB relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table might look like one to many, but Entity Framework will enforce it as optional:optional because of the navigation properties. Since the navigation property is only a single object and not a collection, there is no way to add multiple.

If you look at the generated tables, it creates a nullable foreign key to your principal table (Optional_1). This allows you to create an Optional_2 that is not associated with an Optional_1.

If you were to insert multiple rows into Optional_2 that have the same foreign key to Optional_1 outside of EF, there wouldn't be anything preventing it from going through. If you were to try and load these entities you would get an error. You can't add a unique index to the column because it needs to allow NULL since it is optional.